# Security frontend side

Tags: xss, csrf, audit

Hi i´m a frontend developer and next week we will have a security audit i need to be sure that frontend side is secure and dont have vulnerabilities, so my question is, ¿What would you recommend or wich topics do you know about frontend security?

I readed topics about XSS, CSRF, Clickjacking, NPM audit

Angular escapes XSS scripts so i dont have to worry about that.
I´m using authorization JWT token so i dont need to worry about CSRF. My app doesn´t have vulnerabilities in NPM packages.

I dont know what other things i need to worry about.

Comment: Welcome to the community, I'm afraid your question might be a bit too broad for this site.. Could you please edit and define your scope precisely?

Comment: How do you pass JWT token to the web service?

Comment: @defalt as a bearer token in Authorization header

Comment: Where do you keep it? In cookies?

Comment: @defalt No in localstorage, localstorage is encrypted in AES 256

Comment: Using JWT token does not mitigate CSRF.